# Symfony2 : Installation CCDNMessageMessageBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to install the Symfony bundle CCDNMessageMessageBundle.

To do this I :

- installed Symfony (2.0.17)
- executed `php bin/vendors install` with git
- followed the indications in [here](https://github.com/codeconsortium/CCDNMessageMessageBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/install.md)

The problem comes in step 4 of this documentation (Run vendors install script) :

There are many errors - this are the first lines :

> Installing/Updating CCDNMessageMessageBundle f7ee2c184257011e2991b34ac5cfe9a8b01c6889
>   HEAD is now at f7ee2c1
>   Update documentation
>
> PHP Fatal error: Class `'CCDNMessage\MessageBundle\CCDNMessageBundle'` not found in
>   xxxxxxxxxxxx\app\AppKernel.php on line 20 ...

For information :

AppKernel.php, line 20 contains :

```
new CCDNMessage\MessageBundle\CCDNMessageBundle(),
```

as last element of array `$bundles`.

autoload.php contains this registerNamespaces :

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
  'Symfony' => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles'),
  'Sensio' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
  'JMS' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
  'Doctrine\\Common' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-common/lib',
  'Doctrine\\DBAL' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib',
  'Doctrine' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/lib',
  'Monolog' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/monolog/src',
  'Assetic' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/assetic/src',
  'Metadata' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/metadata/src',
  'CCDNMessage' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
));
```

And at the end of deps I entered :

```
[CCDNMessageMessageBundle]
  git=http://github.com/codeconsortium/CCDNMessage.git
  target=/bundles/CCDNMessage/MessageBundle
  version=v1.2
```

I think I did all the steps in the documentation !

Someone can help me to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Instead of doing crazy html thing for format your code, you should use 4 spaces (check my edit).

Answer (score 1):

The git url in deps is wrong, should be

```
[CCDNMessageMessageBundle]
  git=git://github.com/codeconsortium/CCDNMessageMessageBundle.git
  target=/bundles/CCDNMessage/MessageBundle
  version=v1.2
```

or with HTTP

```
[CCDNMessageMessageBundle]
  git=http://github.com/codeconsortium/CCDNMessageMessageBundle.git
  target=/bundles/CCDNMessage/MessageBundle
  version=v1.2
```

Comment: Thanks ! Now I get the message : 
> Installing/Updating CCDNMessageMessageBundle
The "git" value for the "CCDNMessageMessageBundle" dependency must be set.

Comment: I updated the answer for reflect the full entry. Before I only showed the URI

Comment: This is exactly entered the git entry I entered.
But strange - today I get again the initial error message (PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CCDNMessage\MessageBundle\CCDNMessageBundle' not found in C:\wamp\www\sym003ccdn\app\AppKernel.php on line 20) - I also tried the HTTP version - same result !?